# Resharper 5.1 crashes with Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I have the problem that Resharper 5.1 crashed while VS 2008 SP1 tries to load it.
I got an error message telling me to excute some command line argument which I, i dont know we, didnt read.
Now I have the problem that even a VS and/or Resharper re-install doesnt fix this problem.
It seems that the plugin is disabled.

Anyone had a similar problem and knows what to do in this case?
Or where can I ask for help on this?

Br,
David

Answer (score 1):

Please report this bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net